# How to parse url in php to get numbers and strings

Tags: php

I have url:
http://example.com/list4

I want to parse "list4" in url name to get separated strings and numbers.

And finaly url will be:

```
<?php  echo  'http://example.com/'.$string.$number; ?>
```

I am able to do that now, but:

When I try to replace $url with `$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`, doesn't work. I tried `$url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` but doesnt work too... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$url = "http://example.com/list4";
preg_match("#\/(\w+)(\d+)$#", $url, $matches);
echo "String: " . $matches[1] . "<br>";
echo "Number: " . $matches[2] . "<br>";
// print out the URL you wanted above
echo "http://example.com/" . $matches[1] . $matches[2];
```

---

### EDIT

To fit the needs of the question, you're going to need to account for `.php` at the end of your URL. This is going to work:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
preg_match("#\/(\w+)(\d+)\.?\w*$#", $url, $matches); // updated
echo "String: " . $matches[1] . "<br>";
echo "Number: " . $matches[2] . "<br>";
// print out the URL you wanted above
echo "http://example.com/" . $matches[1] . $matches[2];
```

Comment: This works! But when I try to replace $url with `$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` Doesn't work. I tried `$url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` but doesnt work too... Why?

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic HTTP_HOST is to replace `http://example.com/`, that works. but `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` can be multiple directories (e.g. '/one/directory.php'). in this case, do you need only the last directory ('directory.php')? could you maybe provide an example of what `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` are in your case?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` echo -> http://example.com/list4.php
`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` echo -> lista2
I can use any of this, but maybe second is better. What I need to write in $url?

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic I'm going to edit my answer to fit the needs of this.

Comment: I tried, but strings and numbers echo is empty. When I echo $url, I get -> example.com. And .php extension is rewrited by htaccess. All pages on site doesnt have .php extension. Maybe this cause a problem?

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic you told me three comments above that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` echoes out example.com/list4.php – so now it doesn't? '

Comment: The problem is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only echoes the host, like 'example.com' or 'stackoverflow.com'. You need the whole thing. That means concatenating `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. I'm going to edit.

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic I edited the answer, please update the code too, I edited the regex. Also, please tell me what this returns: `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. All works with `$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Comment: One more question, if page url will be `list104`, is this code still works??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73377/discussion-between-aleksandar-stojanovic-and-jvitasek).

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic Yes, it's going to work. Any combination /stringnumber. Even without the `.php` extension.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
```

$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

echo "
";

$first=preg_match_all('/.*[/]+([a-z]*)?/',$url,$result); 
$string=$result[1][0];

$second=preg_match_all('/.*[/]+[a-z]*([0-9]*)?/',$url,$result); 
$number=$result[1][0];

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$string.$number
?>

Comment: You probably miss something. Code doesnt work...